# Cloudflare CDN integration

Tags: assets, cloudflare

Is it possible to integrate assets with Clouflare CDN service ? In docs only Amazon, Google and Rackspace are referred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloudflare's CDN isn't a true CDN like Amazon, Rackspace, or Google.

With Cloudflare you host your assets on the server and Cloudflare then automatically keeps a cached copy of that.

In other words, you don't upload to CloudFlare, CloudFlare downloads from you.

So on Craft, simply use the "Local folder" source type.